# How can I use dynamically defined enums in FastAPI/Pydantic models run on Uvicorn?

Tags: python, dynamic, fastapi, pydantic, uvicorn

I have a FastAPI application that has some Pydantic models defined. Some of the fields in these models should only allow values that are defined by enums that are loaded from a database and created at runtime.

The setup I have currently works fine when either debugging or running via the python command line however when I run with Uvicorn using `uvicorn main:app` I can see that the enums get loaded successfully but it seems the models get loaded before the enums and as such the app fails to start up successfully with an `ImportError`.

I have a minimal example that shows the issue [on github](https://github.com/ArbitraryId/stackoverflow-example).

I've tried changing it so instead of using an import statement I get the enum definition from the `enum_definitions` singleton declared on line 139 of `models/enums.py`, i.e.

```
Enum1 = enum_definitions.get_enum_definition("Enum1")
```

which triggered the exception on line 104 of `models/enums.py`. I've tried changing it so the enums are loaded both in `main.py` before the FastAPI object is instantiated and in `models/model1.py` before the model class is declared, however all these approaches result in the model not being able to see the enum.

How can I get the model to use these dynamic enums?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason why you can't load the enum definitions synchronously at startup instead of using the lifetime manager/async loop? That way you can be sure that the code runs before your models get imported.

Comment: @MatsLindh as the database connection in my main project is asynchronous, and I need to retrieve the enum definitions from that database, the enum construction needs to happen in an async context.

Comment: But since this is on startup and you need the content before you can actually start your application; what's the need for actually running it async? Why not await the query as soon as possible and retrieve the data before proceeding with launching the application?

Comment: Could you explain how I might go about doing that in the context of the example application?

Comment: Several comprehensive solutions to dynamic enums with Pydantic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75587442/validate-pydantic-dynamic-float-enum-by-name-with-openapi-description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to run this:

1. Instead of importing directly Enum1, make Model class dynamically retrieve when needed, in file models/model1.py

```py
    from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
    from models.enums import enum_definitions
    
    class Model(BaseModel):
        enum_field_name: str
    
        @validator('enum_field_name', pre=True, always=True)
        def validate_enum_field(cls, v):
            Enum1 = enum_definitions.get_enum_definition("Enum1")
            if v not in Enum1.__members__:
                raise ValueError(f"{v} is not a valid value for 

Enum1")
            return v
```

2. Also, update your application startup
   In file main.py, Put after v1 = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

```py
    @app.on_event("startup")
    async def load_enums():
        await enum_definitions.load_definitions(global_import=True)
```

Comment: I like the approach of using a validator, I will try this in my main project and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear, hope this helps

Comment: Ended up going with this solution. Thank you!

Comment: Greatit helped, you are welcome